# Error in windows service. Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have the issue with windows service (32x) at Windows server 2003 sp2 with installed framework 4.0.
The service works fine at my machine, but after installing it at server I see the error durimg work with EF. Service is started fine and calls some methods but during the work with EF I see next error

> An unhandled win32 exception occurred in my.exe [1716]. Just-In-Time
>   debugging this exception failed with the following error: Debugger
>   could not be started because no user is logged on.
>
> Check the documentation index for 'Just-in-time debugging, errors' for
>   more information.

I tried to disable just-in time in my visual studio and reinstall the service but no result.

Does somebody know how to solve the issue?

p.s. the versions of microsoft framework are similar at two machines.

Comment: Hi, do you have some logging in place? I suggest using a logging framework like Log4Net so you can catch all exceptions and dump full stack trace for example in a text file. This is especially important for server side, non UI applications like Windows Services.

Comment: Before I received this error I had changed my code a little. In old code,after OnStart in my windows service I run separate thread which works via Timer and did some job with EF. And at that time I had received next error call stack also related with EF Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information..    at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()  System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemAttributeAssemblyLoader.LoadTypesFromAssembly()

Comment: and so? can you reproduce or detect what the issue is?

Comment: I see via callstack that error occured when I try get some property of EF. But this error occured only at server. On my PC I installed this server in run it and evrything is ok. Database is the same